# can a women initiate divorce in Islam?

Tags: women, talaq

If a man torture his wife physically, mentally or emotionally and she have to face injustice from husband then what should she do in this situation. can she initiate divorce herself? what Islam says about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer your question** : **YES** , she absolutely can .

It is called Khulaa (Arabic for being ripped off from something , in this case the marriage ) , an overview of the proceedings are described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khul%27).
Khulaa is strongly supported by Sunni Islamic institutions worldwide , I also believe Shi'as have a similar system (needs confirmation though) .

**Related Questions** : [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14790/what-are-the-steps-that-the-wife-needs-to-take-to-divorce-her-husband?rq=1) and [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25539/any-other-procedure-for-divorce-for-women-other-than-khula?rq=1)

Comment: I wonder what is the relevance of this statement: "Khulaa is strongly supported by Al-Azhar in Egypt" ...  is it not supported by the rest?

Comment: @UmH I am not sure actually , Al - Azhar is the only institution I am 100% sure was behind its implementation in Egypt . Not sure of any other big institutions that worked with state legislators to have it implemented .

Comment: @SongBird al-Azhar actually is a governmental instrument. And it was never the biggest institution of sunni Islam saying so seems too exaggerated. It was rather originally a fatimi institution.

Comment: Khula' is an established part of Islamic law since before Al-Azhar existed. If Al-Azhar promotes some specific or special interpretation of it, then you should explain that.

Comment: @Medi1Saif , I am familiar with it being previously Fatimid and also previously Shiite , but as it stands now , it is Sunni , yeah .   
As for the exaggeration part , yeah , you're probably right , I got carried away there .

Comment: @UmH Okay valid point , I am not familiar with the specifics of their interpretation , so I believe it is safer to remove it .
Edit Coming ASAP